# Use gitlab and terraform in same gitlab job

Tags: docker, gitlab, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I want to create a GitLab job in which I want to use docker to pull the image and terraform to deploy the resources. But gitlab allows only one single image. How should I use both in same job?

Comment: Without sharing more details it would be hard to help you out, but why do you need to use two images?

Comment: I wanted to do docker login first for my private repository and terraform to apply.

Comment: Neither of those require a separate image though

Comment: How do I pull the image and run terraform from the same job? I don't want to install terraform from apt-get something because I don't want to use public terraform cli(it is because I want to use my custom image of terraform to run terraform and I can't use public available CLI).

Comment: Your question needs more information. You mention something about a custom image as well as various restrictions (which do not make so much sense). Please update the question with all the needed information in order to be able to troubleshoot. Also it would be quite nice if you shared a portion of the CI script you already have in hand.